# How to synchronize two directories with bash code?

Tags: bash

Can any one Help me with bash code not shell command ,to get two folders sync,this what i have tried to do , I need  to synchronize d1 directory with d2  with this code , but with this code all I'm getting the first file in d1 to be copied in d2 without the rest of the file ,and what would be the best way to rewrite this code in the bash file to synchronize  d2 with d1,***I need to solve my problem with bash code not with shell command so please,help with my code and direct me to solve my problem***

#! /bin/bash

```
di1=$(ls d1)


n=${#di1[@]}


for (( i = 1; i <$n+1 ; i++ )); do

      t=$(find d2 -name ${di1[$i]})

    if [[ $t = '' ]]; then

     cp d1/${di1[$i]} d2

    fi

 done
```

Comment: Use rsync for this, much more efficient use of time and it's included by default with most UNIXish type operating systems

Comment: Or use `cp -au` if it only needs to be one way

Comment: but what I'm doing wrong with code, and how to adjust it.

Comment: it's not one way,this synchronize d1 with d2 , and then the same code written synchronize d2 with d1

Comment: To create an array, use `di1=( $(ls d1) )`, although using `ls` to create the list of files is incorrect when any file names could contain white space. `di1=( d1/* )` is the correct way, but you will need to deal with the full path names yourself.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for `unison`, since it seems you want bi-directional synchronization, which is difficult to get entirely correct with `rsync`...

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync -avzh /tmp/src /tmp/dst/
```

Comment: I need to solve my problem with bash code not with shell command so please,help me with my code and direct me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Let me try, we need to clarify exactly what sync means:

Let's say you have two dirs

```
d1
 L f1 10/25 11:40
 L f2 10/25 10:22
 L f4 10/10 08:01
d2
 L f1 10/25 10:11
 L f2 10/26 09:56
 L f3 10/24 11:37
```

where d# is a directory, and f# is a file (and # means any one digit number, if you not figured it out yet), whit theirs timestamps in MM/DD hh:mm.

So you wanna have f4 copied to d2, f3 copied to d1 (no overwritten until here), then copy (and overwrite) d2/f1 with d1/f1 and d1/f2 with d2/f2.

then you should end up with:

```
d1
 L f1 10/25 11:40
 L f2 10/26 09:56
 L f3 10/24 11:37
 L f4 10/10 08:01
d2
 L f1 10/25 11:40
 L f2 10/26 09:56
 L f3 10/24 11:37
 L f4 10/10 08:01
```

Well, all I have done until now, was rephrase your question for be sure that it is in a way I can answer it, so if there is anyone reading it yet, the solution could be is as simple as:

update the existing files in the two direction

```
cp -ur d1 d2
cp -ur d2 d1
```

that's it.

Comment: the 'L' letter is somewhat a tring to draw the directory tree

Comment: thanks @gniourf_gniourf, I thought that should comment this _feature_ of suggested solution, but when it comes to write it here I completely forgot to cite it.